# Maven: A way to skip issue management for selected site deploy

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have created a profile:

```
<profiles>
      <!-- Snapshot profile -->
      <profile>
         <id>snapshot-profile</id>
         <activation>
            <property>
               <name>performSnapshot</name>
               <value>true</value>
            </property>
         </activation>
         <properties>
             <cloud.site.url>http://myrepo/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</cloud.site.url>
            <cloud.site.id>xyz-snapshot</cloud.site.id>
            <cloud.site.name>My Repo</cloud.site.name>
            <cloud.site.deploy.url>scp://myrepo/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/</cloud.site.deploy.url>
         </properties>
         <distributionManagement>
            <snapshotRepository>
               <id>rabbit</id>
               <name>rabbit Snapshot Repository</name>
               <url>http://myrepo/fix-snapshot/</url>
               <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            </snapshotRepository>
            <site>
               <id>${cloud.site.id}</id>
               <name>${cloud.site.name}</name>
               <url>${cloud.site.deploy.url}</url>
            </site>
         </distributionManagement>
      </profile>
</profiles>
```

To run the profile I use the following command : 
    clean site-deploy -DperformSnapshot=true -U

I have jira issue management use for regular site deploy :

```
<issueManagement>
    <system>JIRA</system>
    <url>http://corporate.fake.corp/browse/rabbit</url>
</issueManagement>
```

But I do not want this to be used during my profile site-deploy command. How can I achieve this, any guidance!!!

Comment: Please remove the corporate name from your post. Not good for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose which entries appear under "project information" on your site by configuring the [project-info-reports-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/examples/selective-project-info-reports.html)

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>dependencies</report>
              <report>project-team</report>
              <report>mailing-list</report>
              <report>cim</report>
              <report>license</report>
              <report>scm</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

Include this configuration in you profile, and leave out everything you do not want to be present (issue-reporting) in this case.

Comment: In my case the report was inside a plugin hence we need override the same plugin as is and then skip the report which calls issue management stuff. A bit of repetitive lines but I got some start. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create another build profile which doesn't have `issueManagement`.

Comment: I cannot add issueManagement tag inside profile. Can you point me to an example if any. Also I have big bunch plugins outside profile, in that case do I have to duplicate them in two different profiles?

Comment: ok, what are you trying to achieve by making it not visible for one case?

Comment: I have build tag( with lots of plugins and plugin management tags) , extension tags, issueManagement tag, distributionManagement tag and profile tag. All these are direct childern node of project tag. Can you explain your thoughts, may be I did not get you. I cannot put issueManagement tag inside profile(I get mvn syntax errors). So how can I go about creating two profiles and excluding issue management for one of them?